# How to make expandablelistview with default expand/collapse icon indicator at right?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indicator

I am developing an android app with design.

http://prntscr.com/86wnmm

Here the default icon indicator of exapandablelistview is show in left side.
How can I show this icon indicator at right side of the listview?,
is there any change in Xml file can implement this?

my xml code is

`

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight"
    android:dividerHeight="0.7dp" />
```

`

Comment: try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#attr_android:indicatorRight

Answer (score 10):

It's too easy to do...
Just Follow two steps:

1.)

Just need to add this line in your  ExpandableListView xml file.

```
          android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

2.)Then, in your list item.xml or whatever you named it place these 2 more lines...

```
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

Here you go, The Show is Over!! Just Run it..:)

Answer (score 0):

use below override method with setIndicatorBoundsRelative methods it works for me for lower version below gellybean use setIndicatorBounds method .

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
      mExpandableListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(mExpandableListView.getRight()- 40, mExpandableListView.getWidth());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes working solution for all devices is get Width of expandable list and setIndicatorBound to the right.

Override the below method in your Activity containing Expandable list view.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
mExpandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(mExpandableListView.getRight()- 40, mExpandableListView.getWidth());
}
```

this will be helpful surely.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        expandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(expandableListView.getWidth()-40,expandableListView.getWidth());
    } else {
        expandableListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(expandableListView.getWidth()-40,expandableListView.getWidth());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`android:indicatorLeft` in `<ExpandableListView/>` tag xml

Comment: Add some explanation

Comment: it is similar to adding left margin, but shifts only indicator to right :) just try it, let me know